# Web API to read an Excel file on a server, using availiable options only

Tags: c#, iis, .net-6.0

On a WEB server, we need to upload an Excel file (.xlsx) and parse it.
We use C# and .Net 6.

I am looking for a way to do this, with available tools only. So far I have been suggested to:

1. Ole Automation - does not work, as we do not have Excel or any office software on the server
2. By OleDB connection - Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 - which is also not possible as it is not present on the server and will not be.
3. Using some 3rd part component, for which we might have legal rights and need to pay for license.

None of these options are an option for my project.
Leaving those options out, how would you parse an Excel file?

We only have to read it.

Comment: https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader

Comment: Documentation for XSLX is openly available - feel free to implement your own (not necessary the easiest read... but I don't see any other option based on your restrictions)... Side note: library recommendations questions are off-topic on SO.

Comment: @sa-es-ir thanks, it needed a bit of work, but I have it

Answer (score 0):

There are many such examples. You can try this tutorial.

Create a new project in your Visual Studio.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;    
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;    
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;            
namespace WindowsFormsApplication4    
{    
    public partial class Form1 : Form   
    {   
        public Form1()  
        {
            InitializeComponent();    
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
        {   
            Excel.Application xlApp ;  
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ; 
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;  
            Excel.Range range ;   
            string str;
            int rCnt ;
            int cCnt ;
            int rw = 0;
            int cl = 0;
            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"d:\csharp-Excel.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
            rw = range.Rows.Count;
            cl = range.Columns.Count;
            for (rCnt = 1; rCnt  < = rw; rCnt++)
            {
                for (cCnt = 1; cCnt  < = cl; cCnt++)
                {
                    str = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2;
                    MessageBox.Show(str);
                }
            } 
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
            xlApp.Quit();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
        }
    }
}
```

It needs to add the Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library to you project.

Tutorial link: http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-read-excel.htm

Comment: I cannot use that on a server, as Excel is not there. The solution metioned above works